# How can I compare the columns elements in 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison

I have created a 2d array, so lets say as I did in the code below the array elements shows like this:

3 4

8 2

I want to compare the" ROWS"  and get the minimum number, like what I do with 3 & 4, I get 3 is the min number and with the second row between 8 & 2, I get 2 is the min number.
My problem is that I can't get it to compare the columns as in 3 & 8 to get the max out between them, and 4 & 2.
In the code it just outputs the max number in the rows it still comparing the "ROWS"
P.S sorry for the long explanation. I just had to clarify it .

```
int main()
{
    int d;
    int max;
    //array dimention
    cout << "Enter the array dimention :- " << endl;
    cin >> d;
    //max_min for the final maximum numbers
    int max_num[d];
    //the 2d array
    int arr[d][d];
    // array input
    cout << "please enter the array elements :- " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    //array output
    cout << "the array elements you enterd :-" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //the max numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        max = arr[0][i];
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            if (max < arr[j][i]) {
                max = arr[j][i];
            }
        }
        max_num[i] = max;
    }
    cout << "the maximum elements in array  :-" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        cout << max_num[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanted to insert the code but i dont know how srry im new to this

Comment: i am using dev c++ ide

Comment: Inserting code: paste in the code in question (preferably formatted to meet the requirements of a [mcve]). on the line before the code place three backticks (`). On the line after the code place three backticks. If you try to add too much code, the site will enforce the [mcve] requirement and refuse to let you ask the question until you have reduced the amount of code or justified it with a lot of explanation.

Comment: yeah my code is too long ..

Comment: Then you need to cut it down. Back up the program. Remove everything that has nothing to do with the current problem. You want a program that runs and attempts to compare rows of a 2D array and does nothing else. You build an example array ahead of time, no user input, and try to compare.

Comment: i did it !! thank you soo much !!

Comment: im done with comparing the rows .. i want it to compare the cloumns now not really sure if its called columns but im just explaining it as im seeing it and how i want it to compare

Comment: Note: `int arr[d][d];` is not legal C++ code. It is allowed by extension by a few compilers. Among the reason it is illegal is it a very easy way to overflow the program's stack. A `d` of about 250 will kill the program on most Windows systems.

Comment: Note if you had written this program to perform each of its various functions in their own functions, you would find this very easy to break up into a [mcve].

Comment: thats why i have been seeing the over flow error and i dont get it can u plz show me the right way to do it

Comment: the only problem that im have in the (columns comparing ) (max_num) at the last part of the program but i can't break it cuz it might not be understandable

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you are comparing in rows right now, then just flip the order you index `arr` and you will be comparing in columns: `arr[i][j]` -> `arr[j][i]`.

Comment: i did it thanks guys so MUCH !!